# only strings in influxdb

Tags: redis, logstash, influxdb

i've this config file in logstash

```html
input {

   
  redis{
  host => "localhost"
  data_type => "list"
  key => "vortex"
  threads => 4
  type => "testrecord"
  codec => "plain"

 }
 }

filter {
           kv {
              add_field => {
                "test1" => "yellow"
                "test" => "ife"
                "feild" => "pink"
              }
           }
}

output {

 stdout { codec => rubydebug }

           influxdb {
       db => "toast"
             host => "localhost"
             measurement => "myseries"
             allow_time_override => true
            use_event_fields_for_data_points => true
            exclude_fields => ["@version", "@timestamp", "sequence", "message", "type", "host"]
   send_as_tags => ["bar", "feild", "test1", "test"]
             
  }
      }
```

and a list in redis with the following data:

foo=10207 bar=1 sensor2=1 sensor3=33.3 time=1489686662

everything works fine but every field in influx is defined as string regardless of values.

does anybody know how to get around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `mutate` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.2/plugins-filters-mutate.html) may be what you're looking for here.

```
filter {
  mutate {
    convert => {
      "value"   => "integer"
      "average" => "float"
    }
  }
}
```

It means you need to know what your fields are before-hand, but it will convert them into the right data-type.

Comment: thanks a lot, this solved my problem. i used filer { kv {} ... } for parsing first and after that the mutator ... works great! thanks a lot!